# Ubuntu installer - Where does GRUB install by default?

Tags: grub2

During the Ubuntu 16.04 installation, if not specified manually, on which drive and partition does GRUB install by default on a computer with multiple drives? Does it install on the same drive as ubuntu is installed, or on the first drive on the computer?

Comment: It should install to the boot drive but the core part of it is still on the Ubuntu partition.

Comment: If MBR(msdos) partitioning, grub2 installs the boot loader into sda by default. If using Something Else, then you can choose which drive's MBR to install the boot loader. IF UEFI, grub only installs to ESP - efi system partition on drive seen as sda. But most of grub2, menu, configuration settings & files are in you install.

Answer (score 1):

Grub has a few components or "stages" some are installed in the MBR (master boot record) and some components are installed in the /boot partition, usually the same partition as your ubuntu root or / partition but may be separate if you are using LVM or encryption or if you so configure /boot.

See http://www.golinuxhub.com/2014/03/step-by-step-linux-boot-process.html for details and locations of the various stages.

You need to install grub into the MBR of the disk that boots your Ubuntu installation. Normally this is the first disk, but again you can configure it otherwise and some (most, ?all) BIOS allow you to select which disk to boot from or boot order of your disks / usb / cd. Some (most) bios will also allow you to select which OS to boot (essentially which boot loader to use).

If in doubt, stay with the defaults of the installer.